# Validate Fields Before Sending PHP Mailer email

Tags: php, phpmailer, mailer

I'm an ASP medium level guy, and I'm a complete unknown to PHP and have have true knowledge or syntax structure of PHP. Although I can read it and tell whats its doing, I couldn't formulate my own code to save. So now I have a client where their template is built in PHP and the mail form has been hacked. So now she receives dozens of Russian emails every day from the welcome email form on her site. First I added field validation on the submittal form, but somehow they get around that. I need to add field value verification in the PHP mailer. I want to add IF field.email ends in ".ru", THEN Die END IF, IF field.attorney IsNULL THEN DIE; END IF, IF field.field IsNULL THEN DIE; END IF. What is the syntax for these statements in the PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $template = str_replace(
        array("<!-- @{FromState} -->", "<!-- @{FromEmail} -->"),
        array("Email:", $_POST['email']),
        $template);
}else{
    die('MF003');
}

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $template = str_replace(
        "<!-- @{FromName} -->",
        $_POST['name'],
        $template);
}else{
    die('MF006');
}

if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $template = str_replace(
        array("<!-- @{MessageState} -->", "<!-- @{MessageDescription} -->"),
        array("Message:", $_POST['message']),
        $template);
}
```

Comment: *"IF field.email ends in ".ru""* - That won't help you at all. Those guys can be sending from different top level domains. Plus, there could be legitimate emails coming from that domain. What you could do is to send them a verification email. If they don't respond, and chances are they won't, then ditch the email flag. This should be done at the server level though if you want to block out everything coming from the .ru TLD.

Comment: any reason not to add reCAPTCHA?"

Comment: Like other said above: Filtering based on content isn't going to work. It'll be only a matter of time before the filters are bypassed (and usually not very long). The most obvious solution is adding a CAPTCHA to the form. Most of those spam mails are sent by automated scripts and decent captchas will easily put an end to them. The second step would be to send a confirmation email with a unique url + id that, once clicked, will submit the final form. Though that might inconvenience a lot of visitors

Comment: Sometimes adding a field like `<input name='email' type='text' style='display:none'>` on your form and having another called something unrelated which is where you really put your email address helps weed out bots. Few bots interpret CSS and will blindly fill in fields like this. If that field's populated, it's probably a bot.

Comment: Never use arbitrary from address submitted from a form; only send to fixed addresses known to your script. Otherwise you just make a spam gateway like you've got. This applies regardless of what language you're working in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only reject emails from .ru email addresses, you can use a simple regular expression such as:

```
if(preg_match('/\b.ru\b/', $_POST['email'])) {
    // Error message
}

else {
    // Send email
}
```

However I'm sure there's many ways of bypassing this, such as sending spam mail from another TLD. Of course, a better way would be to prevent spam and bots in general. Methods such as: honeypots, session token verification, spam lists, etc. would be much more effective. [This is a good article](https://zinoui.com/blog/protect-web-forms-from-spam) if you're looking for a place to start.

Comment: if my address was `brian.rubin@gmail.com` it would fail your test

Comment: @IdontDownVote Good catch. I replaced strpos with a regular expression.

Comment: `brian.ru.bin@gmail.com` :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$_POST['attorney'] || !$_POST['field'] || substr($_POST['email'],-3) == ".ru" )
    die('hackers! :)');
```

but it's not really good solution